# Xamarin TabbedPage updateing Icons

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, icons

If got a problem: In my Xamarin Application I have a TabbedPage like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E07Qp.jpg

Now I want to change the displayed Icon of the active tab.(Like the Youtube app)
By creating the TabbedPageContens, I set the diffrent Dark icons. In these content pages i have this code to change the Icon:

```
Appearing += (s, a) => Icon = "icon.png");
Disappearing += (s, a) => Icon = "icon_dark.png");
```

This works fine and in the Content Page, the Icon-Path gets successfully updatet, but in the View it stays the same.

When I debug my application at these positions, I can see that the icon path is changed.

I hope someone can help me :D

Best Regards

Comment: Try to wrap it in a [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/) call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to set the selected state icon built in to the tab bar. It shouldn't be something you set through `Appearing/Disappearing` events. Check out these tutorials by James Montemagno to see what you can do with the images in a `TabBar`.

http://motzcod.es/post/138225183932/tintcolor-selectedimage-xamarin-forms-ios
http://motzcod.es/post/157544468267/xamarin-forms-android-selected-and-unselected-tab-colors

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :D

Comment: @StevenThewissen - Do you have updated links? These don't work anymore, but I'd love to see what you were referencing!